# Why is 0 < -0x80000000?

Tags: c, constants, signed, numeric-limits, numeric-conversion

I have below a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INT32_MIN        (-0x80000000)

int main(void) 
{
    long long bal = 0;

    if(bal < INT32_MIN )
    {
        printf("Failed!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Success!!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The condition `if(bal < INT32_MIN )` is always true. How is it possible?

It works fine if I change the macro to:

```
#define INT32_MIN        (-2147483648L)
```

Can anyone point out the issue?

Comment: How much is `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Have you tried printing out bal?

Comment: IMHO the more interesting thing is that it is true *only* for `-0x80000000`, but false for `-0x80000000L`, `-2147483648` and `-2147483648L` (gcc 4.1.2), so the question is: why is the int literal  `-0x80000000` different from the int literal  `-2147483648`?

Comment: @Bathsheba I just running program on online compiler http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm

Comment: If you've ever noticed that (some incarnations of) `<limits.h>` defines `INT_MIN` as `(-2147483647 - 1)`, now you know why.

Comment: similar: [Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11536389/995714), [Why it is different between -2147483648 and (int)-2147483648](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12620753/995714), [large negative integer literals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8511598/995714)

Comment: Modern compilers warn about `-0x80000000`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc On a standard 32 bit system that supposed duplicate will print "success" just as expected. As opposed to this question which will print "failed", which was not expected. The difference is that the post you linked uses a signed long long literal, instead of an unsigned int literal.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I think C++ is actually far behind C here, since C had a long long type which guaranteed at least 64 bits back in 1999, but C++ doesn't seem have gotten one until 2011? Meaning that C and C++ would have displayed different results until C++11.

Comment: @Lundin The *first* edition of the C++ standard (C++1998) was published only one year before the *second* edition of the C standard (C1999).  I guess WG21 saw no particular hurry about putting out a second edition of C++, despite the significant revisions in C99 that it would have been nice to have uplifted.  Looking back from 2015, that was probably a mistake.

Comment: [Why is 1 not greater than -0x80000000](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27052602/995714)

Answer (score 367, accepted):

This is quite subtle.

Every integer literal in your program has a type. Which type it has is regulated by a table in 6.4.4.1:

```
Suffix      Decimal Constant    Octal or Hexadecimal Constant

none        int                 int
            long int            unsigned int
            long long int       long int
                                unsigned long int
                                long long int
                                unsigned long long int
```

If a literal number can't fit inside the default `int` type, it will attempt the next larger type as indicated in the above table. So for regular decimal integer literals it goes like:

- Try `int`
- If it can't fit, try `long`
- If it can't fit, try `long long`.

*Hex literals behave differently though!* If the literal can't fit inside a signed type like `int`, it will first try `unsigned int` before moving on to trying larger types. See the difference in the above table.

So on a 32 bit system, your literal `0x80000000` is of type `unsigned int`.

This means that you can apply the unary `-` operator on the literal without invoking implementation-defined behavior, as you otherwise would when overflowing a signed integer. Instead, you will get the value `0x80000000`, a positive value.

`bal < INT32_MIN` invokes the usual arithmetic conversions and the result of the expression `0x80000000` is promoted from `unsigned int` to `long long`. The value `0x80000000` is preserved and 0 is less than 0x80000000, hence the result.

When you replace the literal with `2147483648L` you use decimal notation and therefore the compiler doesn't pick `unsigned int`, but rather tries to fit it inside a `long`. Also the L suffix says that you want a `long` *if possible*. The L suffix actually has similar rules if you continue to read the mentioned table in 6.4.4.1: if the number doesn't fit inside the requested `long`, which it doesn't in the 32 bit case, the compiler will give you a `long long` where it will fit just fine.

Comment: "... replace the literal with -2147483648L you explicitly get a long, which is signed."  Hmmm, In a 32-bit `long` system `2147483648L`, will not fit in a `long`, so it becomes `long long`, _then_ the `-` is applied - or so I thought.

Comment: why cant `0x80000000` fit into an `int` on a 32 bit system??

Comment: @A.S.H Because the maximum number an int can have is then `0x7FFFFFFF`. Try it yourself: `#include <limits.h>  printf("%X\n", INT_MAX);`

Comment: I know, it is the maximum *positive* number. the question is, when you specify a number in hex, does it *need* to be positive?

Comment: @A.S.H Don't confuse hexadecimal representation of integer literals in source code with the underlying binary representation of a signed number. The literal `0x7FFFFFFF` when written in source code is always a positive number, but your `int` variable can of course contain raw binary numbers up to value 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused. `ìnt n = 0xFFFFFFFF; cout << n;` displays `-1`. Also `ìnt n = 0x80000000; cout << n;` displays `-2147483648`. I question the statement *"can't fit inside a signed type like int"*. It probably  needs further digging or be stated differently.

Comment: @A.S.H `ìnt n = 0x80000000` forces a conversion from the unsigned literal to a signed type. What will happen is up to your compiler - it is implementation-defined behavior. In this case it chose to show the whole literal into the `int`, overwriting the sign bit. On other systems it might not be possible to represent the type and you invoke undefined behavior - the program might crash. You'll get the very same behaviour if you do `int n=2147483648;` so it is not related to the hex notation at all.

Comment: That's also why you'll find code like this in the [standard C headers](http://repo.or.cz/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/include/limits.h): `#define INT_MIN (-INT_MAX - 1)`

Comment: The behavior of "wrap around" unsigned numbers is fixed by the C++ standard.  It has nothing to do with 2's complement (and only to do with the `sizeof(unsigned)`).  Are you sure it is different in C?

Comment: "Instead, on a two's complement system,"  - actually the system of representing negative numbers does not affect unsigned arithmetic, which is defined in terms of modular arithmetic. In the case of 32-bit int, `-0x80000000` is always `0x80000000`.

Comment: @Lundin out-of-range assignment from integer type to signed integer type is always *implementation-defined*; there are no UB cases

Comment: @M.M I believe the standard says something about an "implementation-defined signal may be raised". What that signal is or what happens if it isn't handled, is not covered by the standard. But sure, I can edit that part.

Comment: The behaviour of signals is part of the Standard; the default handling of each signal is *implementation-defined* too (7.14/4)

Comment: I am surprised that this overly complicated explanation is so popular. It turns out that the comparison (<) has nothing to do with it really, your last two paragraphs seem to be completely irrelevant. Just try to output the value INT32_MIN to see how it is represented.

Comment: @Octopus The paragraph about implicit promotion is relevant: suppose long is 32 bits, and we have a nearly identical example where the other operand is a long with any randomly picked value. Then the usual arithmetic conversions would instead have forced that operand to convert to unsigned, and the expression would have been evaluated in a completely different manner. As for the last paragraph, it answers the question.

Comment: The explanation of how unary `-` is applied to unsigned integers could be expanded a bit. I had always assumed (though fortunately never relied on the assumption) that unsigned values would be "promoted" to signed values, or possibly that the result would be undefined. (Honestly, it should be a compile-error; what does `- 3u` even mean?)

Answer (score 29):

`0x80000000` is an `unsigned` literal with value 2147483648.

Applying the unary minus on this *still* gives you an unsigned type with a non-zero value. (In fact, for a non-zero value `x`, the value you end up with is `UINT_MAX - x + 1`.)

Comment: In this case, `-0x80000000` is `0x80000000`, unsigned, since UINT_MAX+1 is `0xFFFFFFFF+1` = `1ULL<<32`.  (Or actually `0` since UINT_MAX+1 wraps to 0 if you evaluated that expression according to C rules after re-arranging to `UINT_MAX+1 - x`, since addition is associative when signed-overflow UB isn't a factor.)  Fun fact: signed `-INT_MIN` causes signed-overflow UB, unlike any other `int` value.  The most-negative number is its own complement in 2's complement systems.

Answer (score 23):

This integer literal `0x80000000` has type `unsigned int`.

According to the C Standard (6.4.4.1 Integer constants)

> 5 The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding
>   list in which its value can be represented.

And this integer constant can be represented by the type of `unsigned int`.

So this expression

`-0x80000000` has the same `unsigned int` type. Moreover it has the same value
`0x80000000` in the two's complement representation that calculates the following way

```
-0x80000000 = ~0x80000000 + 1 => 0x7FFFFFFF + 1 => 0x80000000
```

This has a side effect if to write for example

```
int x = INT_MIN;
x = abs( x );
```

The result will be again `INT_MIN`.

Thus in in this condition

```
bal < INT32_MIN
```

there is compared `0` with **unsigned** value `0x80000000` converted to type long long int according to the rules of the usual arithmetic conversions.

It is evident that 0 is less than `0x80000000`.

Answer (score 13):

A point of confusion occurs in thinking the `-` is part of the numeric constant.

In the below code `0x80000000` is the numeric constant.  Its type is determine only on that.  The `-` is applied afterward and *does not change the type*.

```
#define INT32_MIN        (-0x80000000)
long long bal = 0;
if (bal < INT32_MIN )
```

*Raw* unadorned numeric constants are positive.

If it is decimal, then the type assigned is first type that will hold it: `int`, `long`, `long long`.

If the constant is octal or hexadecimal, it gets the first type that holds it: `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`.

`0x80000000`, on OP's system  gets the type of `unsigned` or `unsigned long`.  Either way, it is some unsigned type.

`-0x80000000` is also some non-zero value and being some unsigned type, it is greater than 0.  When code compares that to a `long long`, the *values* are not changed on the 2 sides of the compare, so `0 < INT32_MIN` is true.

---

An alternate definition avoids this curious behavior

```
#define INT32_MIN        (-2147483647 - 1)
```

---

Let us walk in  fantasy land for a while where `int` and `unsigned` are 48-bit.

Then `0x80000000` fits in `int` and so is the type `int`.  `-0x80000000` is then a negative number and the result of the print out is different.

[Back to real-word]

Since `0x80000000` fits in some unsigned type before a signed type as it is just larger than `some_signed_MAX` yet within `some_unsigned_MAX`, it is some unsigned type.

Answer (score 12):

The numeric constant `0x80000000` is of type `unsigned int`.  If we take `-0x80000000` and do 2s compliment math on it, we get this:

```
~0x80000000 = 0x7FFFFFFF
0x7FFFFFFF + 1 = 0x80000000
```

So `-0x80000000 == 0x80000000`.  And comparing `(0 < 0x80000000)` (since `0x80000000` is unsigned) is true.

Comment: This supposes 32-bit `int`s.  Although that's a very common choice, in any given implementation `int` might be either narrower or wider.  It is a correct analysis for that case, however.

Comment: This isn't relevant to OP's code, `-0x80000000` is unsigned arithmetic. `~0x800000000` is different code.

Comment: This seems to be the best and correct answer to me simply put. @M.M. he is explaining how to take a twos complement. This answer specifically addresses what the negative sign is doing to the number.

Comment: @Octopus the negative sign is *not* applying 2's complement to the number (!)  Although this seems clear, it's not describing what happens in the code `-0x80000000` !  In fact 2's complement is irrelevant to this question entirely.

Answer (score 8):

C has a rule that the integer literal may be `signed` or `unsigned` depends on whether it fits in `signed` or `unsigned` (integer promotion). On a `32`-bit machine the literal `0x80000000` will be `unsigned`. 2's complement of `-0x80000000` is `0x80000000`  on a 32-bit machine. Therefore, the comparison `bal < INT32_MIN` is between `signed` and `unsigned` and before comparison as per the C rule `unsigned int` will be converted to `long long`.

#### C11: 6.3.1.8/1:

> [...] Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Therefore, `bal < INT32_MIN` is always `true`.