# In C programming standards, what is meant by integer "-127-1U"?

Tags: c, binary

For some reason I am led to believe that this actually refers to -128 as an integer but why not just write -128?

Comment: [*citation needed*] :)

Comment: I don't see it in the [c standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)

Comment: Can you give some context as to where you've seen this, i.e. a compileable piece of code?  You'll get a better answer that way.

Comment: It would be relevant if the `int` size is 8 bits. With my 32-bit `int` the library has `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` because `2147483648` is outside `int` range, so `-2147483648` does not work.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182672/why-is-0-0x80000000

Comment: @WeatherVane: however, the standard guarantees that `int` is at least 16 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-127-1U` is a constant expression.

`127` is an *integer constant*. It is of type `int` and has the obvious value.  The unary `-` operator is applied to it, yielding the value `-127`, also of type `int`.

`1U` is also an integer constant.  The `U` suffix causes it to be of type `unsigned int`.

The second `-` is a subtraction operator, which takes two operands. Under the rules for resolving binary (two-operand) operators with different types, the `int` operand is implicitly converted to `unsigned int`. Converting `-127` from `int` to `unsigned int` (assuming a typical 32-bit 2's complement  representation for `int`) yields `4294967169` of type `unsigned int` (more generally it's `UINT_MAX - 126U`). Subtracting `1U` from that yields `4294967168`, again of type `unsigned int`.

I have no idea what the purpose of this expression might be. I'd have to see more context to speculate. It would be clearer to write `UINT_MAX - 127U`.

Answer (score -2):

They may be trying to determine the size of bits used to hold the data on that particular machine or compiler.  Using an 8 bit sign calculation, the calculation will under flow giving 128 or not underflow giving -128.

Comment: Signed "underflow" is UB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the calculation is in `unsigned int`.

Comment: There is no "U" integer type. A `U` suffix on an integer constant causes it to be of type `unsigned int` (or of some wider unsigned integer type if the value exceeds `UINT_MAX`). `1` is of type `int`; `1U` is of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: @mch Yes, but then it won't "underflow", but first the `-127` will be converted to `unsigned int` by adding `UINT_MAX+1` and then `1u` subtracted.

Comment: So basically -128 would have caused an underflow, which can be overridden by using -127-1U?

Comment: @Team.Coco It is pretty much the same as `(unsigned int)(-128)` (unless `-128` is outside of the range of `int`...)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `-128` cannot be outside the range of `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Can't it be of 8-bit size with sign-and-magnitude representation? Then it would be [-127, +127] range.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No. The range of `int` must be at least `-32767` .. `+32767`. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.2.4.2.1, `<limits.h>`. ((I think some compilers for very small embedded systems use 8-bit `int`, but they're non-conforming.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Hm Wasn't aware of the "*Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.*" statement. Thanks.

Comment: @Keith Thompson:  Sure in 2011, I would expect that of any C complier or system.  I was writing C code back on 8 bit machines.  I would bet the rule didn't apply then.  I would also bet that there is plenty of C code left over from when a 2011 specification was not valid.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk But your answer is incorrect even if everything is 8-bit. In that case the expression will result in `128`.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk: That requirement has been in place at least since 1989. K&R1, published in 1978, doesn't say that int is at least 16 bits, but the examples it shows are all at least that big. If you were using a compiler with 8-bit int after 1989, then it was non-conforming. (That's not necessarily a bad thing. A non-conforming compiler can be perfectly useful. Just think of it as a compiler for a non-C language that's very similar to C.)

Comment: @Eugene Sh:  You are right, it gives 128.  It doesn't change the basic idea that using a calculation will give a different result depending on the number of bits.