# Extract upper and lower word of an unsigned 32-bit integer

Tags: c, cpu-word, uint32, uint16

To extract the upper and lower word of an unsigned 32-bit integer and store each one in separate uint16_t-variables I do as follows (*nbr* is an unsigned 32-bit integer):

```
uint16_t lower_word = (uint16_t) nbr & 0x0000FFFF;  // mask desired word
uint16_t upper_word = (uint16_t) ((nbr & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16); // right-shift after masking
```

Is the explicit conversion to an uint16_t unnecessary? What other more effective ways, if there are any, do you recommend to obtain the desired results instead of this approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
uint16_t lower_word = (uint16_t) nbr;
uint16_t upper_word = (uint16_t) (nbr  >> 16);
```

masks are useless

cast are necessary else the compiler could produce warning

{edit to take into account the remark of Lundin /  Eric Postpischil}

for instance `gcc -Wconversion` produces a warning without the cast

Comment: I see your logic. The masking is seemingly unnecessary.

Comment: The assignments do not violate any constraint in the C standard, so a compiler is not required to produce a warning, and most do not by default, even when “all” normal warnings are requested. GCC, for example, warns only when “-Wconversion” is explicitly requested; this warning is not in its set of “-Wall” warnings.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, Lundin warned ( :) ) me about that in a comment on the next answer, but thank you

Answer (score 8):

The C type system is both subtle and dangerous. The explicit conversion may or may not be necessary. In case of `(uint16_t) nbr & 0x0000FFFF` specifically, the cast is not correct, assuming 32 bit CPU.

You cast before the operation takes place. Meaning that the operand `nbr` will get explicitly converted by the cast, and then immediately implicitly converted up to `int` by implicit integer promotion. The result will be of type `int`, which is signed. Harmless in this case but can cause trouble in other cases. By using the incorrect cast you made a `signed int` out of a `uint32_t` which was not the intention.

Overall you need to be aware of [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Although, there is an implicit lvalue conversion upon assignment back to `uint16_t`, which most of the time saves the day.

Also note that `0x0000FFFF` is dangerous style. Hex literals are of the type where the value will fit, regardless of how many zeroes you put before the value. In this case, it is `int` which is signed. On a 16 bit system, `0x0000FFFF` would give `int` but `0x00008000` would give `unsigned int`. (Check this weird bug for example: [Why is 0 < -0x80000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182672/why-is-0-0x80000000))

The best practice, rugged, portable, MISRA-C compliant code, is code which does not contain any implicit conversions at all:

```
uint32_t nbr = ...;
uint16_t lower_word = (uint16_t) (nbr & 0xFFFFUL);
uint16_t upper_word = (uint16_t) ((nbr >> 16) & 0xFFFFUL);
```

This assuming `nbr` is known to be `uint32_t`, otherwise it is best practice to cast that operand to `uint32_t` before casts.

The masks are not really necessary in this specific case, but in the general case, for example when masking out 4 bytes from a `uint32_t`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As stated initially: "assuming 32 bit CPU". Obviously if `int` or `long` is 64 bit on some garage compiler, swap `UL` for `U`. Seriously, have you nothing better to do than stalking every post I make and come with language-lawyer remarks that are far beyond what any newbie will need to know? This answer is already far too detailed to be pedagogical, without covering portability to obscure garage compilers.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need the typecast and i would recommend not to use one. This is because it has a higher precedence than the & operator, so nbr is first converted to uint16_t and then masked. This is also why the second line would not work without the additional parentheses.

Apart from that the code is just fine, and there is no real reason to use a different approach. You could also do the shift first and then mask the value, but the resulting assembler code should be exactly the same.

Comment: @AbdelAleem Please don't "fix" the question once there are answers posted. Instead fix the actual code :) I will rollback your changes as it makes posted answers irrelevant.

Comment: I disagree, typecast are needed because he wants the result in 16 bits and of course the code must compile without warnings

Comment: The code does compile without warnings, at least on gcc 8.2, even if you use -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra. That said, the casts don't hurt either, at least if operator precedence is respected (so the additional parentheses should always be used)

Comment: @FelixG -Wall at least is mandatory to compile for me, a compiler does not produce warning/error because it is not gentle but because that helps, and the programmer have to take them into account :)

Comment: @bruno i completely agree with you on that, and i actually use -Wall -Wextra on all my code. That's why i did a quick test, and found that gcc doesn't complain if the casts are omitted, even if i add -Wpedantic

Comment: @FelixG oh yes, so strange !

Comment: gcc has a separate warning for potentially dangerous type conversions called `-Wconversion`. It is not included in `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, likely because it gives a high amount of false positives together with spotting real bugs (like a static analyser). `-pedantic` only affects standard compliance and `uint16_t u16 = u32 >> 16;` is fine as far as the standard is concerned.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to repeat this operation multiple times in your code, there is another way of doing so using unions :

```
typedef union _uplow                                                                                     
{                                                                                                        
  struct _reg {                                                                                          
    uint32_t low : 16;                                                                                   
    uint32_t up  : 16;                                                                                   
  } reg;                                                                                                 
  uint32_t word;                                                                                         
} uplow;
```

Declare your variable as follows :

```
uplow my_var;
my_var.word = nbr;
```

Use it like that :

```
printf ("Word : 0x%x\n Low : 0x%x\n Up  : 0x%x\n", my_var.word, my_var.reg.low, my_var.reg.up);
```

Output :

```
Word : 0xaaaabbbb
 Low : 0xbbbb
 Up  : 0xaaaa
```

Comment: This is horribly non-portable, both compiler-specific and CPU-specific. While the OP's code is 100% portable and much better than this. You could use a union between `uint16_t[2]` and `uint32_t` to make it less bad, but you would still have endianess dependence needlessly.

Comment: @Lundin yes, and so complicated at the same time. I down voted this answer, like I did with the now removed answer using the pointer, these two down votes are the only ones I did on S.O. but difficult to not do :(