# Work on an array of signed int as if it contained unsigned values

Tags: c, arrays, casting, signed

I've inherited some old code that assumes that an `int` can store values from -2<sup>31</sup> to 2^<sup>31</sup>-1, that overflow just wraps around, and that the sign bit is the high-order bit. In other words, that code should have used `uint32_t`, except that it wasn't. I would like to fix this code to use `uint32_t`.

The difficulty is that the code is distributed as source code and I'm not allowed to change the external interface. I have a function that works on an array of `int`. What it does internally is its own business, but `int` is exposed in the interface. In a nutshell, the interface is:

```
struct data {
    int a[10];
};
void frobnicate(struct data *param);
```

I'd like to change `int a[10]` to `uint32_t a[10]`, but I'm not allowed to modify the definition of `struct data`.

I can make the code work on `uint32_t` or `unsigned` internally:

```
struct internal_data {
    unsigned a[10];
};
void frobnicate(struct data *param) {
    struct internal_data *internal = (struct internal_data *)param;
    // ... work with internal ...
}
```

However this is not actually correct C since it's casting between pointers to different types.

Is there a way I can add compile-time guards so that, for the rare people for whom `int` isn't “old-school” 32-bit, the code doesn't build? If `int` is less than 32 bits, the code has never worked anyway. For the vast majority of users, the code should build, and in a way that tells the compiler not to do “weird” things with overflowing `int` calculations.

I distribute the source code and people may use it with whatever compiler they choose, so compiler-specific tricks are not relevant.

I'm at least going to add

```
#if INT_MIN + 1 != -0x7fffffff
#error "This code only works with 32-bit two's complement int"
#endif
```

With this guard, what can go wrong with the cast above? Is there a reliable way of manipulating the `int` array as if its elements were `unsigned`, without copying the array?

In summary:

- I can't change the function prototype. It references an array of `int`.
- The code should manipulate the array (not a copy of the array) as an array of `unsigned`.
- The code should build on platforms where it worked before (at least with sufficiently friendly compilers) and should not build on platforms where it can't work.
- I have no control over which compiler is used and with which settings.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty in C but I'd find a way to use a union to map the signed and unsigned data structures to the same memory locations. Then use them however you like.

Comment: Are you sure that `#if INT_MIN != -0x80000000` will work? The header file`limits.h` uses `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` to avoid that, because `2147483648` is not a valid signed value, to negate.

Comment: ... actually in MSVC that works OK, but there is a warning for a variable initialisation

Comment: @WeatherVane It works because `-0x80000000` is of type `unsigned int`. And so `INT_MIN` gets promoted to `unsigned int` too. The reason why compilers define `INT_MIN` like you describe is to ensure that the constant `INT_MIN` itself remains of type `int` rather than `long long`, which wouldn't be too sexy. But then of course MSVC is from the Jurassic period so it might not necessarily have the type `long long` to begin with.

Comment: @Lundin MSVC does indeed have `long long` but its `long` is 32-bit. Maybe your point was a hit on MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

- > However this is not actually correct C since it's casting between pointers to different types.

  Indeed, you cannot do such casts, because the two structure types are not compatible. You could however use a work-around such as this:

  ```
  typedef union
   {
     struct   data;
     uint32_t array[10];
   } internal_t;

   ...

   void frobnicate(struct data *param) {
       internal_t* internal = (internal_t*)param;
       ...
  ```

  Another option if you can change the original struct declaration but not its member names, is to use C11 anonymous union:

  ```
   struct data {
     union {
       int        a[10];
       uint32_t u32[10];
     }
   };
  ```

  This means that user code accessing `foo.a` won't break. But you'd need C11 or newer.

  Alternatively, you could use a `uint32_t*` to access the `int[10]` directly. This is also well-defined, since `uint32_t` in this case is the unsigned equivalent of the effective type `int`.

---

- > Is there a way I can add compile-time guards so that, for the rare people for whom int isn't “old-school” 32-bit, the code doesn't build?

  The obvious is `static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4, "int is not 32 bits");` but again this requires C11. If backwards compatibility with older C is needed, you can invent some dirty "poor man's static assert":

  ```
  #define stat_assert(expr) typedef int dummy_t [expr];
  ```

---

- > `#if INT_MIN != -0x80000000`

  Depending on how picky you are, this isn't 100% portable. `int` could in theory be 64 bits, but probably portability to such fictional systems isn't desired either.

  If you don't want to drag limits.h around, you could also write the macro as

  ```
  #if (unsigned int)-1 != 0xFFFFFFFF
  ```

  It's a better macro regardless, since it doesn't have any [hidden implicit promotion gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182672/why-is-0-0x80000000) - note that `-0x80000000` is always 100% equivalent to `0x80000000` on a 32 bit system.

Comment: `sizeof(int) == 4` doesn't actually tell me whether `int` is a 32-bit type. It could have 16 value bits and 16 padding bits, for example. The reason I want to test `INT_MIN` is that I want to error out if it's -2^31-1. With the union, is it safe to cast a pointer that way? I thought the only permitted aliasing was between structs with a common prefix. C11 is right out: we still avoid most C99 features (`stdint.h` is ok though, everybody has that).

Comment: @Gilles 2's complement implementations won't have padding bits because that would be complete madness. Yes, the union cast is safe since it is a union type that contains an `int[10]` among its members ("strict aliasing rule" C17 6.5 §7).