# How to express hexadecimal as signed and perform opeartion ? MISRA 10.1

Tags: c, misra

Example:

```
int32 Temp;
Temp= (Temp & 0xFFFF);
```

How can I tell that `0xFFFF` is *signed* not *unsigned*. Usually we add a "u" to the hexadecimal number `0xFFFFu` and then perform operation. But what happens when we need a *signed* result ?

Comment: If no suffix provided, then it is a `signed` number. Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: @ZongruZhan No that's wrong, hex constants have different type rules than decimal constants, see C17 6.4.4.

Comment: You should clarify your question. What do you mean with needing signed result? For example, if you start with negative value, do expect to have sign extended value after the masking? (In this case value in range -32768..+32767.) Or something else?

Comment: "How can I tell that 0xFFFF is signed not unsigned. " --> use `_Generic(0xFFFF) ...`.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I tell that 0xFFFF is signed not unsigned.

You need to know the size of an `int` on the given system:

- In case it is 16 bits, then `0xFFFF` is of type `unsigned int`.
- In case it is 32 bits, then `0xFFFF` is of type (signed) `int`.

See the table at C17 6.4.4.1 §5 for details. As you can tell, this isn't portable nor reliable, which is why we should always use `u` suffix on hex constants. (See [Why is 0 < -0x80000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34182672/584518) for an example of a subtle bug caused by this.)

---

In the rare event where you actually need signed numbers when doing bitwise operations, use explicit casts. For example MISRA-C compliant code for masking out some part of a signed integer would be:

```
int32_t Temp; 
Temp = (int32_t) ((uint32_t)Temp & 0xFFFFu);
```

The `u` makes the `0xFFFFu` "essentially unsigned". We aren't allowed to mix essentially signed and unsigned operands where implicit promotions might be present, hence the cast of `Temp` to unsigned type. When everything is done, we have to make an explicit cast back to signed type, because it isn't allowed to implicitly go from unsigned to signed during assignment either.

Answer (score 0):

> How to express hexadecimal as signed and perform operation?

When `int` is wider than 16 bit, `0xFFFF` is signed and no changes needed.

```
int32 Temp;
Temp= (Temp & 0xFFFF);
```

To handle arbitrary `int` bit width, use a cast to quiet that warning.

```
Temp = Temp & (int32)0xFFFF;
```

Alternatively, use a *signed* constant as *decimal* constants, since C99, are always *signed*.

```
Temp = Temp & 65535; // 0xFFFF
```

The alternative idea goes against the "express hexadecimal as signed" but good code avoids naked magic numbers and so the usage of a *hex* constant is less relevant as the concept of the mask should be carried in its name.

```
#define IMASK16 65535
...
Temp = Temp & IMASK16;
```

Comment: 0xFFFF / 65535 aren't MISRA compatible, the `u` suffix is required.

Comment: @Lundin OP was asking about MISRA 10.1.  Are you suggesting a `u` is required for that or for some other MIRSA one (and which one)?

Comment: It's for another rule 7.2 but I'm assuming the OP wants the code to be MISRA compliant no matter which rule they happen to break.

Comment: @Lundin C89 has "unsuffixed decimal `int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`" 6.1.3.2.  C99 uses `int, long , long long`.  So in C89, a decimal consent may be `unsigned long` - not the same as C99.   In OP's case here, that does not apply to `0xFFFF`.

Comment: Ah I see, you are correct.